# Set image height to grow but not overflow flex parent

Tags: html, css

I have a column of flex items. One of the items is an image. I would like this image's height to grow until the max height of the parent flex container is reached.

Here's an example what I have so far:

```js
function toggleImg() {
    let img = document.querySelector('img');
    if (img.style.display === "block") {
    img.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    img.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  border: solid green;
}

.flex-container {
  max-height: 50vh;
  border: solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img-container {
  border: solid blue;
  flex-basis: content;
}

img {
display: none;
   opacity: 0.3;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleImg()">
toggle img
</button>
<div class="flex-container">
  <h2>
  test
  </h2>
  <h2>
  test
  </h2>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200" />
  </div>
  <h2>
  test
  </h2>
</div>
```

I've tried playing around with a few different flex properties, but no luck. I've made a JSFiddle here, with a button to toggle the image: https://jsfiddle.net/9jxes28L/163/

[image: example1]

The image grows to its natural height, pushing the item below it outside of the bounds of the `max-height` (indicated by the red border). I would like the image to grow only to the point where all of the content fits within the `max-height`, without causing any overflow. I don't want to hide overflow either, or make the parent scrollable.

[image: example2]

This code behaves how I would like it to with smaller images. I can't use an explicit `height` on the parent container, because I don't want empty space if the content can't fill the entire container. The closest workaround I've been able to find is setting a `max-height` on the image itself - this works if the content surrounding the image is static, but I would like the content to be dynamic. If more content is added surrounding the image, the image should not grow as much, respecting the `max-height` of the parent.

I hope this makes sense. I've been scratching my head at this for a while now. I'm willing to use any sort of weird janky tricks, Javascript, whatever, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: overflow: auto to the image container